# Include (inherit) only specific block of template

Tags: django, django-templates

My project has two apps (for now),`table` and `menu`. Each app has a template and both templates `extends` a `base.html` template at the project root.

`table_view.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}

{% block title %}Table Mgt{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <link href="{% static "css/table.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  ...some elements here...
{% endblock %}

{% block sidebar %}
  <a href="#">
    <button class="sidebar_button check_in">Check In</button>
  </a>
  <a href="#">
    <button class="sidebar_button check_out">Check Out</button>
  </a>
{% endblock %}
```

`menu_view.html`

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% load static %}
{% block title %}Menu{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
  <link href="{% static "css/menu.css" %}" rel="stylesheet"/>

{% block sidebar %}
  {% include 'table/table_view.html' %}
{% endblock %}
```

`base.html`

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
<body>
  <div id="header">
    ...some elements here...
  </div>    

  <div id="sidebar">
    {% block sidebar %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    {% block content %}
    {% endblock %}
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In `menu_view.html`, I am trying to `include` the block `sidebar` ***only***. However, the entire `table_view.html` is actually embedded.
How do I `include` only a specific block from specific template?

Comment: You don't. You create sidebar.html and include it in both `table_view.html` and `menu_view.html` at the sidebar slot. Blocks are slots where you can put stuff into and override in child templates. They are empty containers you can fill with default content. Include is copy/paste using filenames: take contents of that file and paste it here.

Comment: @Melwyn Thanks. I guess for each block, I have to split it into its own template then. Wish there is a more DRY-way to do this.

Comment: No, only the shared components. Also, if they are the same on each page, then just put the default in the base.html and don't override it. Don't even mention sidebar in the menu_view.html template. If it extends the base, then it'll include the sidebar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template extension works by defining slots you can put stuff into. These slots can be filled with defaults. The slots will be rendered as is if you don't override them in the extending (child) templates.

For example with this base:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>{% block title %}Hello World!{% endblock %}</title>
  <link href="{% static "css/base.css" %}" rel="stylesheet" />
  {% block extra_css %}{% endblock %}
</head>
</html>
```

And this child:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
```

The result will be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link href="/static/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>
</html>
```

With this child template:

```
{% extends "base.html" %}
{% block extra_css %}<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">{% endblock %}
```

The result is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Hello World!</title>
  <link href="/static/css/base.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
</html>
```

Now specific to your problem:

- if you have different sidebars, try to make the sidebar.html template smarter so it can render all variations -or- create different sidebar templates
- if you have the same sidebar everywhere, but some pages don't have a sidebar, create different base templates: one with a sidebar slot and one without.
- if each sidebar is different for each page, don't bother with include and just override the slot